# Changing background image using useState and onClick with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image, use-state

I have been going in circles trying to make this work. My goal is to have a background image that displays behind a link after it is clicked. Each Link on my Navigation has its own image for when clicked. The first error I was experiencing was too many re-renders. I manipulated the code more, the error went away however the images are still not rendering onClick.
Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated, I am still pretty new to React and would love to understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Logo from '../../assets/images/Platform-Logo.svg'
import artistPaintBackground from '../../assets/images/Navigation-Artists-SVG.svg'
import eventsPaintBackground from '../../assets/images/Navigation-Events.svg'
import contactUsPaintBackground from '../../assets/images/Navigation-Contact-Us.png'
import homePaintBackground from '../../assets/images/Navigation-Home.png'

const navLinks = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: `HOME`,
        path: `/`,
        bgI: '',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'EVENTS',
        path: '/events',
        bgI: '',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: `ARTISTS`,
        path: `/artists`,
        bgI: '',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: `CONTACT US`,
        path: `/contactUs`,
        bgI: '',
    },
]

const Nav = (props) => {
    const [navLinksBackgroundImage, setNavLinksBackgroundImage] = useState({
        navLinks: [
            {
                id: 0,
                title: `HOME`,
                path: `/`,
                bgI: '',
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'EVENTS',
                path: '/events',
                bgI: '',
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: `ARTISTS`,
                path: `/artists`,
                bgI: '',
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: 'CONTACT US',
                path: `/contactUs`,
                bgI: '',
            },
        ],
    })

    const css = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${navLinks.bgI})`,
        width: '20%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    }

    const addBgIHandler = () => {
        setNavLinksBackgroundImage({
            navLinks: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    title: `HOME`,
                    path: `/`,
                    bgI: ` ${homePaintBackground}`,
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'EVENTS',
                    path: '/events',
                    bgI: `${eventsPaintBackground}`,
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: `ARTISTS`,
                    path: `/artists`,
                    bgI: `${artistPaintBackground}`,
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'CONTACT US',
                    path: `/contactUs`,
                    bgI: `${contactUsPaintBackground}`,
                },
            ],
        })
        if (navLinks.id === 0) {
            return `${homePaintBackground}`
        } else if (navLinks.id === 1) {
            return `${eventsPaintBackground}`
        } else if (navLinks.id === 2) {
            return `${artistPaintBackground}`
        } else if (navLinks.id === 3) {
            return `${contactUsPaintBackground}`
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position='static' className={classes.navBar}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Container maxWidth='xl' className={classes.navDisplayFlex}>
                        <Link to='/'>
                            <img className={classes.imageLogo} src={Logo} />
                        </Link>
                        <Hidden smDown>
                            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                                <List
                                    component='nav'
                                    aria-labelledby='main-navigation'
                                    className={classes.navDisplayFlex}
                                >
                                    {navLinks.map(({ title, path, bgI }) => (
                                        <Link
                                            active={bgI}
                                            to={path}
                                            key={title}
                                            value={bgI}
                                            className={classes.linkText}
                                            onClick={addBgIHandler}
                                            style={css}
                                        >
                                            <ListItem disableGutters={true}>
                                                <ListItemText primary={title} />
                                            </ListItem>
                                        </Link>
                                    ))}
                                </List>
                            </ThemeProvider>
                        </Hidden>
                        <Hidden mdUp>
                            <Dropdown navLinks={navLinks} />
                        </Hidden>
                    </Container>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Nav
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues

There are a few errors in this code.  The first one I see is on this line:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${navLinks.bgI})`,
```

`navLinks` is an `array`, so it doesn't have a `bgI` property.  The individual elements of the array are objects with a `bgI` property.

The next confusing thing is the `addBgIHandler` function.  This function calls `setNavLinksBackgroundImage` and updates the state to one where *every* link has an image for its `bgI`.  It then goes through a bunch of `if`/`else` cases and returns a *single* `bgI`.  But this returned value is never used anywhere.

#### Solution

In general you want to store the minimal amount of information in state that you need. If something never changes then it doesn't need to be in state.  The only changing information that we need to know here is *which link was clicked?*

I'm going to keep your `navLinks` array defined outside of the component, but change it so that it includes the `bgI` for every image.  We want to *know* the `bgI` for each link, but that doesn't mean we will *show* the `bgI`.

We will use a state to tell us which link (if any) is the active link.  I am using the `id` but it doesn't matter.  You could use the `title` or the `path` instead.

```
// Should the initial state be home? Or no active link? That's up to you.
const [activeLinkId, setActiveLinkId] = useState(0);
```

We will only show the background image on a link if it is the active link.  Instead of a constant `css` we will need to make it a function so that it can be different for each link.  We are going to call this function from inside `navLinks.map`, so we can pass in the arguments that we need.  We will need the `id` in order to compare it to the `activeLinkId` state and the `bgI` to set the background image if it's active.

I would recommend that you move the styles `width: '20%', height: '100%',` which are always present into your `classes` object and just handle the background image here.

```
const createCss = (id: number, bgI: string) => {
  if (id === activeLinkId) {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(${bgI})`,
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
    };
  } else return {};
};
```

In my own code I would use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of `if`/`else` but I want to keep this clear and readable.

In the `Link`, we call the function to set the `style` prop.

```
style={createCss(id, bgI)}
```

Our new `addBgIHandler` is so simple that we can define it inline.  When this link is clicked, we set the `activeLinkId` to this `id`.

```
onClick={() => setActiveLinkId(id)}
```

#### Code

```
const navLinks = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: `HOME`,
    path: `/`,
    bgI: ` ${homePaintBackground}`
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "EVENTS",
    path: "/events",
    bgI: `${eventsPaintBackground}`
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: `ARTISTS`,
    path: `/artists`,
    bgI: `${artistPaintBackground}`
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "CONTACT US",
    path: `/contactUs`,
    bgI: `${contactUsPaintBackground}`
  }
];

const Nav = (props) => {
  // Should the initial state be home? Or no active link? That's up to you.
  const [activeLinkId, setActiveLinkId] = useState(0);

  const createCss = (id: number, bgI: string) => {
    if (id === activeLinkId) {
      return {
        backgroundImage: `url(${bgI})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
      };
    } else return {};
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.navBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Container maxWidth="xl" className={classes.navDisplayFlex}>
            <Link to="/">
              <img className={classes.imageLogo} src={Logo} />
            </Link>
            <Hidden smDown>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <List
                  component="nav"
                  aria-labelledby="main-navigation"
                  className={classes.navDisplayFlex}
                >
                  {navLinks.map(({ title, path, bgI, id }) => (
                    <Link
                      to={path}
                      key={title}
                      className={classes.linkText}
                      onClick={() => setActiveLinkId(id)}
                      style={createCss(id, bgI)}
                    >
                      <ListItem disableGutters={true}>
                        <ListItemText primary={title} />
                      </ListItem>
                    </Link>
                  ))}
                </List>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </Hidden>
            <Hidden mdUp>
              <Dropdown navLinks={navLinks} />
            </Hidden>
          </Container>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Nav;
```

#### React Router

I've answered the question exactly as you've presented it, which is *"how do I show an image on a link when it's clicked?"*  But I see that the `Link` component is imported from `react-router-dom` so I think that you aren't asking the right question.  The question should be *"how do I show an image for the current page link?"*  That question has a different answer which doesn't use state at all.

You can replace your `Link` components with [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink).

> A special version of the `<Link>` that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

Isn't that what we want?  With `NavLink` we can ditch the `useState` and the `onClick` and the `createCss`.  Instead we set our background styles to the `activeStyle` prop, which will only apply these styles when the link is active.

```
{navLinks.map(({ title, path, bgI }) => (
  <NavLink
    to={path}
    key={title}
    className={classes.linkText}
    activeStyle={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${bgI})`,
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
    }}
  >
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, that is really helpful. I will work on implementing your suggestions!! Thank you, thank you!!

Comment: I wanted to try and implement your NavLinks suggestion, however right now it is displaying the home background image always, I see in your comment you say it is up to me what the initial state is, but I cannot figure out how to make it only show up when the link is active. I appreciate your help.

Comment: We are looping through the `navLinks` array and setting the `activeStyle` background to the `bgI` for this element of the array.  You should get the correct image as long as each item in the array has the correct `bgI` property.

Comment: I guess the better question would be how do I prevent the home bgI from displaying when I am no longer on home page. Currently using the above code it is displaying the correct bgI when the link is clicked but the home bgI still remains visible when not on home page. I’m sorry, I’m still learning and at times everything is pretty confusing. With that being said, I appreciate you responding and providing more clarity. My biggest struggle is finding the help I need to better understand what’s in front of me.

Comment: Hmm, I would think the `NavLink` would take care of that?  Can you post a CodeSandbox demo?

Comment: Ok here is the working code sandbox demo.     https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-dxbm4

Comment: It seems like the others are deselecting but "Home" is selected always because all paths match "/".  You would need the [`exact` prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool).

Comment: So I do have exact on the routes already. const Pages = () => {
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/events/:eventId' component={EventPage} />
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path='/events' component={EventsPage} />
    <Route exact path='/artists/:artistId' component={ArtistPage} />
    <Route exact path='/artists' component={ArtistsPage} />
   </Switch>.            is there somewhere else I am supposed to put exact to make it work?

Comment: Yes, add exact to the NavLink

Comment: Thank you soooooo much for walking me throught this! You have been most helpful!! Adding exact to the NavLink worked perfectly! You are my hero! :)